# Detect and Read jumbo QRcode

Tags: java, c++, image-processing, qr-code, zxing

I would like to detect and read [jumbo QR-code](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/QRcode.png) into images. I said jumbo, because they are really big as you can see into the image example.

As I work mainly in java, I tried to use zxing, that seems to be the most common and efficient library. Even if zxing works really well on regular QR-codes (I tested it), it performs really poorly on jumbo QR-codes: detection is around 10%, and it cannot read such big codes.

Would you know a library able to detect and read such jumbo codes? I work mainly in Java, but I am open to C/C++  library too.

Comment: I've just used ZXing on that code and it works fine. I think the issue may be that the image is quite blurry and not well defined.

Comment: I've tried it on images without blur and perfectly defined, it didn't work. Did you use any particular options?

Comment: I just used the ZXing Android app. I pointed my phone at the screen and it scanned it instantly.

Comment: I use the classical java version :(

Comment: But I don't need the algorithm to run on android. Is there a way to use the android version on a classical JVM?

Comment: I think it's the same code. Try it and see.

Comment: I'have downloaded the library and it contains two different and specific codes. The one for android uses android libraries.

Comment: What is the resolution of the Camera and from what distance are you scanning

Comment: We used a bridge, resolution 3000x5300, and we tried many distances and enlightenment conditions. The QR-code example I share is a crop from one of the image test.